# How to get Windows Workflow templates in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, workflow-foundation

I'm working through the book [Pro WF Windows Workflow in .NET 3.5](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430209755) and on page 5 it shows them opening a new project in Visual Studio 2008, "Visual C#/Workflow" is selected and 8 templates are showing:

- Empty Workflow Project
- Sequential Workflow Library
- SharePoint 2007 State Machine W...
- State Machine Workflow Library
- Sequential Workflow Console Application
- SharePoint 2007 Sequential Workflow
- State Machine Workflow Console Application
- Workflow Activity Library

However in my (German) Visual Studio 2008, even after installing SP1, under Workflow I just have:

- Sequenzieller SharePoint 2007-Workflow
- SharePoint 2007-Statuscomputerworkflows

and under WCF I found:

- Sequential Workflow Service Library
- State Machine Workflow Service Library

But how do I get the Visual Studio 2008 Workflow templates that are mentioned in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of VS are you using? I'm running VS2008 Team Suite (SP1), and I get all 8 templates mentioned. Perhaps try a re-install on a virtual machine, to see if it was an install failure?

Comment: I have the Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition installed, good idea with the virtual machine.